# Invoke-Command and add computer name column

Tags: powershell

How can I add some computername column like `PSComputerName`?

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $cpu {
  Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
    Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "app"} |  
    Select-Object PSComputerName, DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
    Format-Table PSComputerName, DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate
} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-File $logFile
```

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to rename the PSComputerName column to ComputerName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry key you're reading doesn't have a value `PSComputerName`. You can add it with a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx), though:

```
Select-Object @{n='PSComputerName';e={$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, DisplayName, ...
```